# Unable to get data into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, defaulttablemodel

I'm trying to get the data from a `JTextField` to a `JTable` when the button Add

`ActionListener`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object src = evt.getSource();
    if (src == AddBtn) {
        System.out.println("HELLOO");
        String nextRowId = Integer.toString(model.getRowCount());
        model.addRow(new Object[] { nextRowId, LatText.getText(),
                LongText.getText(), EvlText.getText() });

    } else if (src == NextBtn) {

    } else if (src == perviousBtn) {

    }
}
```

JTable:

```
String columns[] = { "ID", "Name", "Age", "Gender" };
Object data[][] = { { "0", "Tom", new Integer(20), "Male" },
        { "1", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
        { "2", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" },
        { "3", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" },
        { "4", "Raj", new Integer(19), "Male" },
        { "5", "Tina", new Integer(18), "Female" }

};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/9R9QyXdw?

Nothing happens when Add is clicked.

EDIT

I've corrected it to this:

```
 JTable dataTable = new JTable(model);
```

but still no data gets added.
Thank you.

Comment: Please learn and respect Java naming conventions. Having a `Table` and `table` variable is a real PITA when going over your code

Comment: @Robin cheers for pointing out, I will change it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

The first has already been pointed out `JTable table = new JTable(data, columns)` is basically constructing it's own model, so when you try and add something your model in the action listener it's not the same model as that being used by the table.

The other is you declare the model twice.

You declare model as a class global field `DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns)` and then re-declare it again in your `addComponents` methdod...

```
    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
```

So, even if you declared your table as `JTable table = new JTable(model)` it would still be using the wrong model..

Change the declaration of the table as described and remove the declaration of the `DefaultTableModel` model within the `addComponentsToPane` method and it should work fine...

Answer (score 2):

The reason that nothing happens is that you update a `TableModel` which is not set on any `JTable`.

You use

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
```

to construct the table, instead of

```
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Comment: I've just tried what you have suggested but still nothing comes up.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code, but when you create your `JTable` (as read from your pastebin link), you use the following line:

`JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);`

You should specify your model instead of the raw data, the modifications mades to the model will show in your table:

`JTable table = new JTable (model);`

Comment: I've just tried what you have suggested but still nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

When I look your code, you haven't used the TableModel which you are updating into the Table.

If you want to notify your JTable about changes of your data, use
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()

Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29

Updated here, Check it now
http://pastebin.com/bb00PzjD

Comment: Normally there is no need to call `tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()` from an external source. A decent `TableModel` implementation knows when it is changed and fires the event itself. Unrelated: when posting a link to the javadocs, better to post a link to the latest javadoc (1.7) iso the 1.4 javadocs

Comment: @Robin Yes you are right, thanks robin. Further I will use latest javadoc.